# DNS, What is the proper nameserver?

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system

Currently when I lookup my domain in whois, my nameserver is:

```
Name Server: NS0.DNSMADEEASY.COM
Name Server: NS1.DNSMADEEASY.COM
Name Server: NS2.DNSMADEEASY.COM
Name Server: NS3.DNSMADEEASY.COM
Name Server: NS4.DNSMADEEASY.COM
```

My dedicated server is hosted in `Psychz.net`, and having problems with my dns, what is supposed to be the proper nameserver? `NS1.psychz.net`? or `NS1.domainname.com`?

Please advise.

Comment: What about you sort that out with the proper place? WHich would be dnsmadeeasy.com support obviously. Then grab a book about how DNS works and realize that the server location is exactly irrelevant. We do not teach basics here, as per site FAQ.

Comment: My main problem is actually I cannot send email outside my domain. So I googled something and I come up with this DNS Problem, am I on the right track?

Comment: Again, we do not provide beginner support. Having no clue how the internet works? Do not try to fix, hire a professional. This site is ONLY for professional administration. Be at least so polite to read the site FAQ.

Comment: If your problem is really about email....ask questions about email.  Google "XY Problem" please.

Answer (score 2):

Try the below to setup your DNS pointing to `psychz.net`

Check for the following -

1. Wherever you have registered the Domain, check for the DNS entry at the registrar for your domain and change the same to the IP setup by `psychz.net`
2. Alternatively the Hosting service provided should have added the hostname pointer to point to a specific IP for the IP assigned to your system, In this case you may need to add the multiple DNS server IP of `psychz.net`

As of the time of this the following was the result to know the DNS entry for `psychz.net`, may be both are setup to serve the query from external,

```
dns2.psychz.net   (216.24.195.249)
dns1.psychz.net n (216.24.195.249)
```

you may need to talk to your hosting service provider to get this resolved if it is still pending after checking the above.

You may have to change it on the control panel provided to you by `psychz.net`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes the problem was in the psychz.net, I have post a support ticket on them because when i ran dig there was no dns, and they fix it. Thank you. I TomTom is right, I really need to read a book about unix.